# Default parameter value in this __init__() method's definition?

Tags: python, named-parameters, default-parameters

I am looking at some python code to control a camera and having some trouble understanding it due to being new at python.  I see that the `src` parameter is set to `0`.  Does this mean that if a `src` is not given `0` will be used otherwise the given `src` will be used?

```
class WebcamVideoStream:

    def __init__(self, src=0):
        # initialize the video camera stream and read the first frame
        # from the stream
        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
```

so if I do something like this

```
vs = WebcamVideoStream(3)
```

then the `src` will be `3`?
and if I do this

```
vs = WebcamVideoStream()
```

then `src` will be `0`?

Comment: Yes indeed, that's the concept behind a default parameter. You can also name the parameter **explicitly**, like `WebcamVideoStream(src=14)`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

Comment: @cricket_007: Nah, you want the section on [default argument values](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values). Keyword arguments are syntactically similar but not very related.

Comment: That type of construct in a function definition is called a "keyword argument" and always include a default value if it's omitted when the function is actually called.

Comment: @user2357112 Right. I missed that OP didn't mention calling with `Stream(src=<value>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer is - yes.

If you run:

```
vs = WebcamVideoStream(3)
```

`src` equals to 3

if you run:

```
vs = WebcamVideoStream()
```

src equals to 0(default value).

As an additional Python's feature, Python supports *args and **kwargs for cases when you're not sure how much and which arguments will be used in your method(it's very general explanation, but I hope it's clear).

Some example of using **kwargs I've posted here:
http://codepad.org/E7m3PnVr

P.S.

1) use *args when you're not sure how many arguments might be passed to your function, i.e. it allows you pass an arbitrary number of arguments to your function.

2) **kwargs allows you to handle named arguments that you have not defined in advance